# jar with lib dependency, along with aar

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I have created a set of jars, that include nothing except native .so file.
I wrote the following gradle task to do it:

```
ext.createNativeJarTask = { platform ->
    def jniLibTask = task("generate${platform}Artifact", type: Jar) {
        classifier = "native-${platform}"

        from "${projectDir}/jniLibs/${platform}"
        into "lib/${platform}"

        destinationDir = file("$buildDir/native")
    }
    return jniLibTask
}
```

this works fine, and with this task I have create 4 separate native jars for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, mips

Now I try to add this as dependency to my apk project:

```
    dependencies {
      compile "com.my.domain:mylib:1.00"
      compile "com.my.domain:mylib:1.00:native-x86"
}
```

and this works fine too

But when I am trying to add native jar along with @aar version of my lib, it simple do not add .so file to apk! Result apk file do not contains x86 .so file!

```
dependencies {
          compile "com.my.domain:mylib:1.00@aar"
          compile "com.my.domain:mylib:1.00:native-x86"
    }
```

How can I use my native jar dependency along with aar??